# Pivot query in Microsoft SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, ms-access, pivot

I am a new to sql server and I have been trying for the last couple of days to transform a simple TRANSFORM query in Access to SQL Server.

In access the query looks like :

```
TRANSFORM tblDefHolidays.colDate
SELECT    tblDefHolidays.colDate
FROM      tblDefHolidays
WHERE     tblDefHolidays.colDate >= DateAdd ("d", -60, date()) 
          AND tblDefHolidays.colDate <= DateAdd ("yyyy",2, date())
GROUP BY  tblDefHolidays.colDate
ORDER BY  tblDefHolidays.colCal DESC 
PIVOT     tblDefHolidays.colCal;
```

In SQL Server the table tblDefHolidays is defined as follows :

```
colCal          nvarchar(40)    
colDate         date    
colCodeBB       nvarchar(20)    
colDesc         nvarchar(255)
```

This is my current SQL Server query which is not running.

```
SELECT colDate, colCal
FROM 
(
   SELECT dbo.tblDefHolidays.colDate, dbo.tblDefHolidays.colCal
   FROM   dbInv.dbo.tblDefHolidays) as [subTable]
PIVOT
(  max(colDate)
   FOR  dbInv.dbo.tblDefHolidays.colCal
    IN ([OSAKA],[LIFFE],[HKEX],[EUREX],[CME],[CBOE])
) as [pivotTable]
```

When running the current sql server query I get :

> Msg 107, Level 15, State 1, Line 9 The column prefix
>   'dbInv.dbo.tblDefHolidays' does not match with a table name or alias
>   name used in the query. Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 2 Invalid
>   column name 'colDate'.

The result (from Access) should look like :

```
 colDate         OSAKA         LIFFE         HKEX        EUREX      CME       CBOE
 7/1/2014                  7/1/2014         
 7/4/2014                  7/4/2014      7/4/2014
 7/21/2014  7/21/2014                   
 8/25/2014  8/25/2014               
 9/1/2014                  9/1/2014      9/1/2014
 9/9/2014                  9/9/2014         
 9/15/2014  9/15/2014                   
 9/23/2014  9/23/2014                   
 10/1/2014                 10/1/2014
```

Thanks for reading.

Best,

Manu

Comment: What 'not running' means? Do you have any error message to share with us? **Where do you select the pivoted columns? (You listed the original fields in the outer query instead of the pivoted fields)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following. After the SourceTable subquery you should no longer refer to fields via dbInv.dbo.tblDefHolidays the alias SourceTable takes over

```
SELECT
      [OSAKA]
    , [LIFFE]
    , [HKEX]
    , [EUREX]
    , [CME]
    , [CBOE]
FROM (
            SELECT
                  dbo.tblDefHolidays.colDate
                , dbo.tblDefHolidays.colCal
            FROM dbInv.dbo.tblDefHolidays
      ) AS SourceTable
      PIVOT
      (
      MAX(colDate)
      FOR colCal IN ([OSAKA], [LIFFE], [HKEX], [EUREX], [CME], [CBOE])
      ) AS PivotTable
;
```

attempt at variant with redundant column (don't be mad, its technically redundant)

```
SELECT
      displayDt
    , [OSAKA]
    , [LIFFE]
    , [HKEX]
    , [EUREX]
    , [CME]
    , [CBOE]
FROM (
            SELECT
                  convert(varchar,dbo.tblDefHolidays.colDate,101) as displayDt
                , dbo.tblDefHolidays.colDate
                , dbo.tblDefHolidays.colCal
            FROM dbInv.dbo.tblDefHolidays
      ) AS SourceTable
      PIVOT
      (
      MAX(colDate)
      FOR colCal IN ([OSAKA], [LIFFE], [HKEX], [EUREX], [CME], [CBOE])
      ) AS PivotTable
ORDER BY
      displayDt
;
```

I have guessed at MM/DD/YYYY style 101 for that date column.

You should be able to add an order by clause that references a field in the select clause
see: [BOL](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx)

There is NO way to structure the query without naming the columns (OSAKA, LIFFE, etc.)
In Access there may be no need to do that, here there is.

Comment: Thanks for the help. When running your query I get : 
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Invalid column name 'colDate'. 
I tried dbo.tblDefHolidays.colDate instead but that did not solve the problem.

Comment: mmm, I hadn't noticed but as you only have 2 fields in the source there really isn't anything to `pivot on`, try it by removing coldate from the select clause (as it is above now). let me know what happens.  Edit this answer with any error message (don't use comment)

Comment: I know you want an additional row, but I can only guess that this will work.

Comment: ok, stop editing the answer now - I suggested that for error messages only, it'ds not working - so please just use comments